# poetry: first added library version higher than allowed by project python version

Tags: python, python-poetry

I've created a new environment using `poetry` and `python3.7` and am trying to install the first package in the project: `numpy`.

When I run `poetry add numpy` I get the following error:

```
Using version ^1.22.4 for numpy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.0s)

  SolverProblemError

  The current project's Python requirement (>=3.7,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
    - numpy requires Python >=3.8, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.7,<3.8
  
  Because no versions of numpy match >1.22.4,<2.0.0
   and numpy (1.22.4) requires Python >=3.8, numpy is forbidden.
  So, because base-env depends on numpy (^1.22.4), version solving failed.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

  • Check your dependencies Python requirement: The Python requirement can be specified via the `python` or `markers` properties
    
    For numpy, a possible solution would be to set the `python` property to ">=3.8,<4.0"

    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies,
    https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#using-environment-markers
```

The instructions in the stack trace advise me to change my Python version to `3.8`, but I need to stay within `3.7`. So I have two questions:

1. Why does `poetry` attempt to use a `numpy` version that is incompatible with my Python version?
2. How do I get `poetry` to install a `numpy` version that is compatible with my Python version (`3.7`)?

I manage my Python versions with `pyenv` and since my global Python version is set to `3.7.9`, `poetry` automatically assumes that version during intialization:

```
python --version
> Python 3.7.9
```

This is how I initialized my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "base"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Base environment"
authors = ["pinco-pallo <pinco-pallo@email.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Comment: maybe there is another package in your project that requires higher numpy version? You can try to manually set numpy version in `pyproject.toml`

Comment: This is the first package I'm trying to install, so that should not be the case. I've clarified that in the question.

Comment: and what happens if you enter specific (and compatible) version of numpy in `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: maybe you have `poetry.lock` file with that numpy version set?

Comment: The dependencies would be specified in `poetry.lock` but since this is the  first package there is no `poetry.lock` to modify. I think it would be created upon the addition of the first package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `numpy` release that fulfill the projects python requirement (>=3.7,<4.0).

- numpy >=1.22 requires python >=3.8
- numpy >=1.21, <1.22 requires python >=3.7,<3.11

You can pin the projects python requirement to `>=3.7,<3.11` and help Poetry finding the numpy version that support it by `poetry add "numpy@~1.21"`.

If you need to support python >=3.11 you have to use [multiple constraints dependency definitions](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/dependency-specification/#multiple-constraints-dependencies) in the `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
numpy = [
    {version = "<1.22", python = "<3.8"},
    {version = "^1.22", python = "^3.8"}
]
```

Run `poetry lock --no-update` and `poetry install` after editing your `pyproject.toml` to lock and install the dependencies.